# PineScript - sequence of color bars doesnt start whre it is supposed

Tags: pine-script

I have 2 indicators (kRSI and kOBG) and I want to paint the graph  with green vertical bars when both indicators is increasing. An adittional restriction is that each sequence of green bars must start when kRSI < 20.

My solution doesn't work properly because the sequence doesnt't only start when kRSI < 20!!

```
//@version=4    
rsi0 = rsi(close, lengthRSI)    
rsi1 = rsi0[1]    
kRSI = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)    
pRSI=plot(kRSI, "StochRSI", color=color.red, linewidth = 2 )  
obv0 = cum(sign(change(close)) * volume)    
obv1 = obv0[1]    
kOBG = sma(stoch(obv1, obv1, obv1, lengthStoch), smoothK)    
pOBV=plot(kOBG, "StochOBV", color=color.lime, linewidth = 2 )    
var float emSubida = na
    
if emSubida == na        
    emSubida := (kRSI[0] < 20 ) and (kRSI[0] > kRSI[1]) and (kOBG[0] > kOBG[1])? 1 : na
else        
    emSubida := (kRSI[0] > kRSI[1]) and (kOBG[0] > kOBG[1]) ? 1 : na        

bgcolor(emSubida==1 ? color.green : na)
```

Comment: Can you share your full code or at least how you calculate kRSI and kOBG?

Comment: Hi Baris. I have all the code there now.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition had some problems and also I would add variables types when you define a variable.

If I understood you right, the following should do the job:

```
rsi0 = rsi(close, lengthRSI)    
rsi1 = rsi0[1]    
kRSI = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)    
pRSI=plot(kRSI, "StochRSI", color=color.red, linewidth = 2 )  
obv0 = cum(sign(change(close)) * volume)    
obv1 = obv0[1]    
kOBG = sma(stoch(obv1, obv1, obv1, lengthStoch), smoothK)    
pOBV=plot(kOBG, "StochOBV", color=color.lime, linewidth = 2 )

var bool canPlot = false
var bool condStart = false
bool checkRsi =  (kRSI > kRSI[1]) and (kOBG > kOBG[1])

if (condStart == false)     // Check the start condition
    condStart := (kRSI < 20 ) and checkRsi
    
canPlot := condStart and checkRsi
condStart := canPlot        // Reset condStart

bgcolor(canPlot == 1 ? color.green : na)
```

It will start when `kRSI` is less than 20 and both `kRSI` and `kOBG` are increasing. It will stop when either `kRSI` or `kOBG` not increasing anymore.
[image]

Comment: Many Thanks.  It works perfectly.
But.. Idontunderstand whymy solution doesn't work. Do you have any insight?

Comment: I tried now to use emSubida as boolean (as you do) instead of  na and 1 ..and now it works.  !?!?!?  na cannot be used in a float variable?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how `na` is treated in pinescript. But you don't need a float here. Better to use `bool` variables for such purposes.